# react-material-ui-carousel - Navigation buttons outside the image content

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-material-ui-carousel

I'm trying to implement a **carousel with React** using the [react-material-ui-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-carousel) library. I want the next and previous **navigation buttons to appear outside** the images something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ywFL.png). [The docs for that library](https://github.com/Learus/react-material-ui-carousel#default-styles) suggest customization is possible by overriding the **navButtonsWrapperProps** attribute of the Carousel component. But I still cannot get the nav buttons out of the image. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know its to late but I have faced same problem. This answer can help someone.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import Carousel from 'react-material-ui-carousel'; // Carousel library
```

You can control carousel next/previous from outside button click using useRef

```
const sliderRef = useRef(null);

<Carousel
ref={ sliderRef }
>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
</Carousel>
```

Then you can use onClick event on any Button

```
const handlePrevSlide = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(sliderRef?.current){
        sliderRef.current.prev();
    }
}

const handleNextSlide = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(sliderRef?.current){
        sliderRef.current.next();
    }
}
```

[image: You can see I am using custom buttons to control next previous actions]

It Works great for me

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem not too long ago. I solved the problem by making the Carousel component's width larger than the carousel item itself. That way the navigation button will come outside of the item as it's item will have less width thatn its parent. Just make sure to align the Carousel and its item to center.

```
<Carousel className={styles.carousel}>
    <Item className={styles.item} />
</Carousel>

// Inside your css
.carousel{
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.item{
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I don't think my solution is optimal but it's a quick fix for the given issue.